# Given $4$ variables and $5$ pairwise products, find the $6$th pairwise product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> Consider four positive numbers (not necessarily integers). The pairwise products are $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, plus one more number.
>
> What is the 6th product? What are the numbers?

I found this from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Consider-4-numbers-The-product-of-any-two-numbers-is-2-3-4-5-6-Out-of-the-possible-6-products-between-the-numbers-5-are-given-What-is-the-6th-product) and I would be interested in a nice solution!

If we name the four numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and the missing product $p_6$, then all of the possible products are:

$$x_1 x_2,\quad
x_1 x_3,\quad
x_1 x_4,\quad
x_2 x_3,\quad
x_2 x_4,\quad\text{and}\quad
x_3 x_4$$

There are six equations and five unknowns, but I don't know how to assign the six different numbers to each of them.

I understand that the partial products which do not share a common factor (for example, $x_1 x_2$ and $x_3 x_4$) should not be assigned to numbers which do have a common factor, for example $2$ and $4$, or $2$ and $6$, or $3$ and $6$.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this myself - I don't think any of the replies there is correct!

Comment: Are these meant to be integers?  But:  The only way to get a prime $p$ as a product is $1\times p$.  Thus, since $2,3,5$ are on the list of products, we need to have $1,2,3,5$ on the list of numbers, hence, that's the full list.  Which does not work since $10,15$ are not among the products.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?  I expect some information has been omitted.  If it's online, please provide a link.

Comment: @lulu good point, not necessarily integers. I edited my question.

Comment: "*I understand the partial products which do not share a common factor*"... since you aren't working exclusively with integers, "factors" are now meaningless as everything is a factor of everything else (*except zero*).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Consider-4-numbers-The-product-of-any-two-numbers-is-2-3-4-5-6-Out-of-the-possible-6-products-between-the-numbers-5-are-given-What-is-the-6th-product

Comment: @JMoravitz yes you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can separate the six products into three pairs with each pair having different factors
$$x_1\cdot x_2\quad \ x_3\cdot x_4\\
x_1\cdot x_3\quad \ x_2 \cdot x_4\\
x_1 \cdot x_4\quad \ x_2 \cdot x_3$$
When we multiply the partial products on each line, we should get the same result.  The only two pairs that have the same product are $2 \cdot 6$ and $3 \cdot 4$, so the product of the last line must also be $12$.  The sixth partial product is $$\frac {12}5$$
Now we can check that the solution works.  By symmetry we can assign the first line $2 \cdot 6,$ the second $3 \cdot 4$ and the last $5 \cdot \frac {12}5$ but we cannot be sure of the order of the last.Then $\frac {x_3}{x_2}=\frac 32.$  If the last is $5 \cdot \frac {12}5$ then $\frac {x_4}{x_2}=\frac 52, \frac {x_1}{x_2}=\frac 54$.  The product of them all is $12$, so we have
$$\frac 32\cdot \frac 52 \cdot \frac 54 x_2^4=12\\x_2=\sqrt{\frac 85}\\
x_1=\frac 54\sqrt {\frac 85}\\x_3=\frac 32\sqrt{\frac 85}\\x_4=\frac 52 \sqrt{\frac 85}$$
If we switch the products in the last line, we get another solution
$$x_2=\sqrt{\frac {10}3}\\
x_1=\sqrt {\frac 65}\\x_3=\sqrt{\frac{15}2}\\x_4=\sqrt{\frac{24}5}$$
We can permute the assignment of the variables at will.

Comment: Stunning wave of thought! Really astounding idea!!!

Answer (score 4):

We have the linear system
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
   0 & 1 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   {\ln x_{\,1} }  \cr 
   {\ln x_{\,2} }  \cr 
   {\ln x_{\,3} }  \cr 
   {\ln x_{\,4} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   {\ln p_{\,1} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,2} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,3} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,4} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,5} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,6} }  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf M}\;{\bf y} = {\bf p}
$$
The rank of the coefficient matrix is $4$, and so  the rank of the [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix)
shall be not greater than $4$.
This pose a constraint on the values and on the order of the $p_k$.

We can have a better look to the situation if we perform a Gaussian elimination on  the augmented matrix.
We do that by performing a LU decomposition of $\bf M$ and then right-multiplying by the inverse of the L component,
and arrive to
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & { - 1} & 1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & { - 1} & 1  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 2  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   {\ln x_{\,1} }  \cr 
   {\ln x_{\,2} }  \cr 
   {\ln x_{\,3} }  \cr 
   {\ln x_{\,4} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   { - 1} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & { - 1} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   { - 1} & { - 1} & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1 & { - 1} & { - 1} & 1 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 0 & { - 1} & { - 1} & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   {\ln p_{\,1} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,2} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,3} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,4} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,5} }  \cr 
   {\ln p_{\,6} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$

It is evident that the system is solvable, and has a unique solution, if and only if the $p_k$'s satisfy the last two equations, i.e. if
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \ln p_{\,2}  + \ln p_{\,5}  = \ln p_{\,3}  + \ln p_{\,4}  \hfill \cr 
  \ln p_{\,1}  + \ln p_{\,6}  = \ln p_{\,3}  + \ln p_{\,4}  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad p_{\,1} p_{\,6}  = p_{\,2} p_{\,5}  = p_{\,3} p_{\,4} 
$$
and this gives a general method to solve this type of problems.

With the data you give, the only way to have two couples with the same product is $2 \cdot 6 = 3 \cdot 4$, and therefore
$$
2 \cdot 6 = {{12} \over 5} \cdot 5 = 3 \cdot 4
$$
which means
$$
{\bf p}^{\,T}  = \left( {\ln 2,\ln \left( {{{12} \over 5}} \right),\ln 3,\ln 4,\ln 5,\ln 6} \right)
$$
Then the upper four equations are readily solved to give
$$
{\bf y} = {1 \over 2}\left( {\matrix{
   {\ln {6 \over 5}}  \cr 
   {\ln {{10} \over 3}}  \cr 
   {\ln {{24} \over 5}}  \cr 
   {\ln {{15} \over 2}}  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf x} = \left( {\matrix{
   {\sqrt {{6 \over 5}} }  \cr 
   {\sqrt {{{10} \over 3}} }  \cr 
   {\sqrt {{{24} \over 5}} }  \cr 
   {\sqrt {{{15} \over 2}} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
and in fact
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sqrt {{6 \over 5}} \sqrt {{{10} \over 3}}  = 2\quad \sqrt {{6 \over 5}} \sqrt {{{24} \over 5}}  = {{12} \over 5}\quad \sqrt {{6 \over 5}} \sqrt {{{15} \over 2}}  = 3  \cr 
  & \sqrt {{{10} \over 3}} \sqrt {{{24} \over 5}}  = 4\quad \sqrt {{{10} \over 3}} \sqrt {{{15} \over 2}}  = 5\quad \sqrt {{{24} \over 5}} \sqrt {{{15} \over 2}}  = 6 \cr} 
$$

However, swapping the values of $p_1$ and $p_6$ we get a different quadruple as result
$$
{\bf x} = \left( {\matrix{
   {\sqrt {{{18} \over 5}} }  \cr 
   {\sqrt {10} }  \cr 
   {\sqrt {{8 \over 5}} }  \cr 
   {\sqrt {{5 \over 2}} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
which checks as well.

I did not check for the other allowed permutations of $\bf p$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the four numbers are $0<a<b<c<d$  Note:  we can assume they are distinct since no products are repeated.

Let the six products be $P_1≤P_2≤\cdots ≤P_6$.

It is easy to see that these must be of the form $$ab<ac<\{bc,ad\}<bd<cd$$

Where the order of the two terms in the middle is uncertain.

If we assume that $P_6>6$ then we get $$\frac {P_1\times P_6}{P_2}=P_5\implies \frac {2P_6}{3}=6\implies P_6=9$$

But there are no solutions for $(a,b,c,d)$ consistent with this (brute force).

Similarly we can not have $P_1<2$.

If we had $P_2$ as the missing term then we'd get $$\frac {2\times 6}{5}=P_2\implies \boxed {P_2=\frac {12}5}$$

That one works!  Indeed we could have $$a=2\sqrt {\frac 25}\quad b=\sqrt {\frac 52}\quad c= 3\sqrt {\frac25}\quad d=\sqrt {10}$$

I did not try to analyze the other cases, though this would be no harder.